# In a functional component, where would I place a console.log to test if the component rerenders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

How I can check when a functional component updates and/or rerenders?

In a class component, I can use `componentWillUpdate` to `console.log` a message.
Where would I place the `console.log` in a functional component to get the same console output?

I see two places, the function body of the component, I would put it right at the start.
And inside the jsx. Would those give me the same result?

I am asking since I can't get `React.memo` to work, and I am wondering if I test the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the effect hooks in React 16.8
[offical document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });
```

Comment: I was just posting an answer and show your answer. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

So you stated you could use " componentWillUpdate to console.log a message."

Please note that the following lifecycle methods :

- componentWillMount
- componentWillReceiveProps
- **componentWillUpdate**

are no longer encouraged.
[Read more](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html)